# Replacement of spaces in variable strings in for loops

Tags: string, batch-file

Let us say I have text file with **some** strings that have spaces in them and in addition there are empty lines at random locations in the file.
Using the parsing of the for command, a copy of the file can be got sans the blanks if and only if none of the strings has any spaces in it.The following illustrates my point:
Using `for /f %%N in (names.txt) do echo %%N` 
returns John instead of the original string ---John Carpenter-- because of the blank space in between.
Now using the same command with options set as tokens=* will make it return the entire name in this case and all other names in the file but the downside is you reproduce all the blank lines in the original file.
Now my idea is to ensure that none of the strings in the original file has spaces in it and then use the for /f command to compact the text file.
My approach would be to first use the for /f with tokens=* option to extract all the strings in the original file one by one and substitute the gaps in the strings with "_". **How do you do this in a for loop ?**
The resulting text file will retain the blank lines in between but they can be easily got rid of by using the default for /f command on the intermediate result which now has hyphenated names.

Comment: `for /F` does _not_ reproduce any empty lines; however lines containing only delimiters (spaces) will be returned.  And just for info.: option set `"tokens=*"` removes any leading delimiters (spaces), where option set `"delims="` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (hi.txt) do (
    set word=%%a
    echo !word: =_!
)
pause>nul
```

Is this what you want for?

Comment: Spot on ! Thank you . I was confused by this:                                                                                                    "This variable substring syntax only works for CMD environment variables, like %MYVAR%, it will not work with FOR parameter variables, like %%G, however a simple workaround is to set a variable first: Set %MYVAR%=%%G and then find the substring of the new variable."                                                                                              http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html